# Include 'ALL' option in dropdownlist bind using ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I have bind the dropdownlist in view by Viewbag from controller as following :

```
ViewBag.test = from p in _userRegisterViewModel.GetEmpPrimary().ToList().Where(a => a.UserType_id != Convert.ToInt32(Session["loginUserType"].ToString()))
                           select new
                           {
                Id = p.EmpId,
                Name =  p.First_Name.Trim() + " " + p.Last_Name.Trim()
            };
```

In view I have bind as following :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.test, "Id", "Name"),
                        new { @class = "form-control", id="ddlEmp" })
```

Now i want to Insert "ALL" and "--Select--" in this dropdownlist.. How can i do this..
Can anyone help me to do this..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can add the `"--Select--"` option using one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem},System.String%29) of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts `optionLabel`. But adding `ALL` makes no sense - how would it bind to a property that is `int`

Comment: I have tried with @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.test, "Id", "Name"),"ALL"
                        new { @class = "form-control", id="ddlEmp" }).. But its not working..

Comment: What is not working? That code will generate the first option as `<option value="">ALL</option>` But selecting it will post back a value of `null` meaning that `ModelState` will be invalid. It only makes sense when you use `"--Select--"`

Comment: I agree with you - how would it bind to a property that is int- but in this case how can do that

Comment: Then use a  view model and bind to a property which is `string` or `int?` so you can test the value when you submit. But if you want both `"--select--"` and `"ALL"` then you will need to create `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the controller and add `SelectListItem` for each item in your collection plus another for `"ALL"`

Comment: yes i want to add both 'select' and 'all' options..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102989/discussion-between-kavisuja-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `null` option to the dropdownlist by using one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%3Ccode%3E2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%3C/code%3E0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%3Ccode%3E0,%3C/code%3E1%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String%29) of `DropDownlistFor()` that accepts a `optionLabel`, for example

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.test, "Id", "Name"), "--select--", new { @class = "form-control", id="ddlEmp" })
```

which will generate the first option as `<option value="">--select--</option>`

However, if you want to include options with both `"--select--"` and `"ALL"` you will need to generate you own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the controller and pass it to the view. I would recommend using view model with a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property for the options, but using `ViewBag`, the code in the controller would be

```cs
List<SelectListItem> options = _userRegisterViewModel.GetEmpPrimary()
    .Where(a => a.UserType_id != Convert.ToInt32(Session["loginUserType"].ToString()))
    .Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = a.EmpId.ToString(),
        Text = a.First_Name.Trim() + " " + a.Last_Name.Trim()
    }).ToList();
// add the 'ALL' option
options.Add(new SelectListItem(){ Value = "-1", Text = "ALL" });
ViewBag.test = options;
```

Note that I have given the `ALL` option a value of `-1` assuming that none of your `EmpId` values will be `-1`

Then in the view, your code to generate the dropdownlist will be

```cs
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpId, (Ienumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.test, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Not sure why your wanting to change the `id` attribute from `id="EmpId"` to `id="ddlEmp"`?

Then in the POST method, first check if `ModelState` is invalid (if the user selected the `"--select--"` option, a value of `null` will be posted and the model will be invalid), so return the view (don't forget to reassign the `ViewBag.test` property).

If `ModelState` is valid, then check the value of `model.EmpId`. If its `-1`, then the user selected `"ALL"`, otherwise they selected a specific option.