# How can we implement to add a select all option in Kendo Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

How to add an option "All" in kendo dropdownlist.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("SampleDDL")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataSource
    (
        datasource => datasource.Read(read => read.Action("GetNames", "Sample"))
    )
    .OptionLabel("--- Select ---")
)
```

Comment: You will need to add it to the collection your `GetName()` method is returning - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286658/include-all-option-in-dropdownlist-bind-using-viewbag/35304780#35304780) for an example